# Find the first digit of $2^{100}$ without using logarithms or Newton's binomial.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, number-comparison

> Find the first digit of $2^{100}$ without using logarithms or Newton's binomial.

I already have the answer, it's $1$ and the number of digits is $31$, but the proof uses logarithms and this question is for inferior grades - they didn't learn about this kind of stuff.

I think the idea is to prove  $10^{30} \lt 2^{100} \lt 2 \cdot 10 ^ {30}$ , but I cannot do it without logarithms.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: But $2^{100}<10^{31}$, no?

Comment: @lulu I don't know, can you prove it?

Comment: Sure.  $2^{10}=1.024\times 10^3$  Thus $2^{100}=(1.024)^{10}\times 10^{30}$.  then an unpleasant (but not difficult) calculation shows that $(1.024)^{10}\approx 1.27$.

Comment: I believe it's $10^{30}$

Comment: @lulu, your comment is the answer.

Comment: @mrnovice Right, I've made the correction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We start by remarking that $2^{10}=1024=1.024\times 10^3$.  It follows that $$2^{100}=(1.024)^{10}\times 10^{30}$$

Clearly $1<(1.024)^{10}$.  If we can prove that $(1.024)^{10}<2$ we'll know that the first digit is $1$.

We remark that $$1.024<1.03 \implies (1.024)^2=1.048576<1.05$$

This in turn implies that $$(1.024)^4<(1.05)^2=1.1025<1.1$$

Continue:  $$(1.024)^8<(1.11)^2=1.2321<1.25$$

And finally $$(1.024)^{10}=(1.024)^8\times (1.024)^2<1.25\times 1.05=1.3125<2$$  And we are done.

Comment: $(1.024)^2=1.0609$ is not correct, and at the end it should be "then".

Comment: @TMM  Thank you!  I was surprised that the estimate was so far off the mark.  And, I must confess I generally choose randomly between "then" and "than".  Same with "compliment" and "complement".

Comment: There is a logic to it - than is for comparisons (bigger than a dog, better than you) while then is to when what that is to what, if you understand what I mean ;)

Answer (score 1):

We need to show these "inferior grade" students that $10^{30}<2^{100}<2\cdot 10^{30}$.  We compute $2^{10}=1024>10^3$. Raising both sides to the $10$th power gives the first inequality.

For the second, we note that $2^{10}<1.03 \times 10^3$.  Square both sides:

$$2^{20}<1.0609 \times 10^6 < 1.1\times 10^6.$$

Square again:

$$2^{40}<1.21 \times 10^{12} <1.3 \times 10^{12}.$$

Square again:

$$2^{80} < 1.69 \times 10^{24} < 1.7 \times 10^{24}.$$

Then compute:

$$2^{100} =2^{80}2^{20} < 1.7\times 10^{24}\times 1.1\times 10^6 =1.87\times 10^{30}<2\times 10^{30}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$2^{100} = (1024)^{10}\\
10^{30}<1000^{10} <1024^{10}=2^{10}$
That establishes the lower bound.

Now we need to show that

$2^{100} < 2\times 10^{30}\\
2^{99}< 10^{30}\\
2^{33}<10^{10}$

$(2048)^3< (2050)^3\\
2050\cdot 2050\cdot 2050 = (4202500)(2050) = 9\times 10^9 < 10^{10}$

$10^{30}< 2^{100} <2\times 10^{30}$